# Why 'for .. in' allowed in closures?

Tags: for-loop, foreach, f#, closures, immutability

Mutable values are not allowed in closures, but the `for .. in` expression is ok. In C# the for loop updates the iterator, but not in F# as it seems. How and why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

F#'s `for .. in` is equivalent to C#'s `foreach` loop, not C#'s `for` loop. And since C# 5, the `foreach` loop does *not* update the iterator; it instead creates a new variable for each iteration through the loop (this has important implications for closures; see [Foreach now captures variables! (Access to modified closure)](http://kristofmattei.be/2013/04/26/foreach-now-captures-variables-access-to-modified-closure/)  for details. This is also what F# does: if you write

```
for txt in ["abc"; "def"; "ghi"] do
    printfn "%s" txt
```

then you're actually creating *three* new string variables when you run that loop, not just one.

To prove to yourself that F# is creating a new variable each time, try the following not-very-functional code:

```
let actions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Action<unit>>()
for txt in ["abc"; "def"; "ghi"] do
    actions.Add(fun () -> printf "%s " txt)
for action in actions do
    action.Invoke()
```

If `txt` was the same variable each time through the `for .. in` loop, this would print `ghi ghi ghi`, just like C# 4 and earlier would have -- because the anonymous function closed over the variable, and after the loop the variable contains `ghi`. But if you run the above code, you'll see that it prints `abc def ghi`, like C# 5 and later do.

So the answer to your question is that F# allows `for .. in` in a closure because it's **not actually mutating anything**.

Comment: Great answer, thanx.